# ScalaFx Bind ImageView to custom Enumeration

Tags: scala, binding, javafx, scalafx

I just started to write scalafx application and have a question about bindings.

I have an Enumeration with connection status in my presenter class and I want to select appropriate icon in label in view class. I basically can create binding in javafx way and set converter which will select appropriate ImageView every time status changes, but is it possible to do in ScalaFX way?

I looked many scalafx examples, but still can't find anything like this.

Here is some code:

```
package view

import scalafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty

class MainWindowPresenter {
  object DatabaseState extends  Enumeration {
    type DatabaseState = Value
    val NOT_CONNECTED, IDLE, BUSY, ERROR = Value
  }

  val login = new ObjectProperty[String](this, "login", "awesomeloginname")
  val state = new ObjectProperty[DatabaseState.DatabaseState](this, "state", DatabaseState.ERROR)
}
```

View class:

```
package view

import java.util.concurrent.Callable
import javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding

import collection.immutable.HashMap

import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem

import scala.util.Random
import scalafx.beans.property.{ObjectProperty}
import scalafx.geometry.{Orientation, Insets, Pos}
import scalafx.scene.control._
import scalafx.scene.image.{ImageView, Image}
import scalafx.scene.layout._

import scalafx.Includes._

class MainWindowView extends BorderPane {
  val model = new MainWindowPresenter

  top = new HBox {
    content = List(
      new Label() {
       graphic <== //somehow select imageview depending on model.state
      }
    )
  }

  private def imageFromResource(name : String) =
    new ImageView(new Image(getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(name)))
}
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for grammar mistakes, if any - English isn't my native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) or the snapshot (2.0-SNAPSHOT) version of [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX) to create the binding. Both are Java libraries, but they are easy to use from Scala. This is the EasyBind way:

```
graphic <== EasyBind.map(model.state, stateToImage)

val stateToImage: Function1[DatabaseState.DatabaseState, ImageView] = {
  // convert state to ImageView
}
```

This code uses the implicit conversion from Scala's `Function1` to Java's `Function`.

You could also define an implicit conversion from ScalaFX `ObjectProperty` to EasyBind's `MonadicObservableValue` and then the first line above can be rewritten to:

```
graphic <== model.state.map(stateToImage)
```

Comment: Thanks! I used EasyBind solution for now, but ReactFX looks much more interesting, I think I'll use it for future code.

Comment: ReactFX 2.0 is going to absorb all the functionality from EasyBind, and most of it is already there in the snapshot release, but it is not yet documented. So yes, I suggest using ReactFX for the future.